# RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path - Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to configure Swagger in Quarkus.
My version of Quarkus: 1.9.2.Final

My dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And my properties resources:

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
```

When I launch my application with: mvn compile quarkus:dev and go to this url:

`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui_not_found/`

A red page with the additional endpoints is shown (ok, this is what I want)
[image]

However, if I make a package with maven (mvn package) and then, launch the jar, the same url returns:

`RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path`

This is the trace:

```
2020-11-10 07:58:08,244 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-1) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /favicon.ico
2020-11-10 07:58:08,246 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-1) RESTEASY002305: Failed executing GET /favicon.ico: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:70)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:47)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:481)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:332)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:253)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
```

I've read in [Quarkus guides](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#use-swagger-ui-for-development) that if you set:

**quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true**

You make it available in production too, but in my case It doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the exception stack and other details?
Moreover, if the path is `/swagger-ui`, why are you trying to hit `/swagger-ui2`?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with the stacktrace. On the other hand, I'm trying to hit the wrong url because I want to see the 404 Resources Page instead a blank page with an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the swagger-ui page, or the 404 page with the links on ?
As far as I know, the 404 with the links is only available in DEV mode.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the 404 page with the links, because sometimes, in Production, users hit the wrong url and I want to show the correct links! Thx

Comment: Like I said, as far as I know that is only available in dev mode. You should be able to build this yourself. Add a Exception `@Provider` that loads your own page. Something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690339/how-to-customly-handle-recourse-urls-not-found-in-quarkus

Comment: Ok, thank you! I thought that It would work in Production mode too, so I will do manually. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

By adding `quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true` to `application.properties`, you will get SwaggerUI in the prod-mode jar as well (accessible at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/)

See the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#quarkus-swaggerui_quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include) for more details.

Also note that this property is a **build-time** property, therefore changing it at runtime has no effect.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but It doesn't work (see the final of my post)

Comment: See my update about the fact that the property is a build time property.